# Two questions in mathematical logic.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I'm studying for a test, and I have this two questions that I do not manage to solve.

The first question will be: Given a language ($\ \mathbb N, *, +, 1 $) show that the group $\{ 3^n : n \in \mathbb N\}$ is defineable in $\mathbb N$.

The second question will be: Define a language as you want, and find a closed formula $\phi$ s.t every model that supplies the formula $\phi$ is finite and is of size $\ n*(n-1) : n \in \mathbb N$.

Now I've tried to maybe consider a language with a function f, I will define f as a bijection by writing a formula that indicates it is a bijection, and will create f as a function $ f: A \mathrm X A -> |M| $, where A is some subgroup of the model M, now if I create a bijection, this means $|A \mathrm XA| = |M|$ but this only means that |M| must be of size $n^2$. I'm having a difficulty understanding how can I create $n*(n-1)$.

Comment: Please make a separate post for each question. In the first question, by "group" I think you mean "set"? By the way, does $\mathbb N$ start with $0$ or $1$?

Comment: For the first question, note that $x\in\{3^n:n\in\mathbb N\}$ if and only if every divisor of $x$ is either equal to $1$ or else divisible by $3.$

Comment: The second question does not make much sense as stated, probably a bad translation. I'm *guessing* that the problem asks for a closed formula $\phi$ such that $\{|M|:M\text{ is a finite model of }\phi\}=\{m(m-1):m\in\mathbb N\}.$ (In that case $\phi$ will also have infinite models, by the compactness theorem.)

Comment: Observe that, if $|A|=n,$ then $|\{(x,y)\in A\times A:x\ne y\}|=n(n-1).$

Comment: Even with all the problems you managed to answer my questions perfectly. Thank you very much !